# Mac OS X pstopdf utility defaults to Letter page size

Tags: terminal, pdf, postscript

I am using the `a2ps` utility from Homebrew to pretty print code, generating `.ps` files, and then the Mac OS X utility `pstopdf` (used by Preview.app) to convert these to `.pdf` format. But whatever page size is specified in the PostScript, the generated PDF files have a Letter page size of 11 x 8.5 inches.

For example

```bsh
a2ps --medium=A4 -P file myfile.py
```

or

```bsh
a2ps --medium=A3 -P file myfile.py
```

generate PostScript files with the correct page dimensions (A4 and A3 respectively) but when converted to PDF by `pstopdf` the resulting PDF is Letter size with the output truncated at the right/ bottom edge of the page.

I can't find any mention anywhere of how to specify what default page size `pstopdf` uses.  Opening the PostScript files in Preview.app uses `pstopdf` in the back end so I get the same result.

Comment: Can you provide an examples of the .ps, to check that it has `setpagedevice` instructions and DSC commands? pstopdf falls back to Letter in the absence of any other page size.

Comment: I can confirm that `a2ps` does not include any `setpagedevice` instructions by default, possibly because these are Level 2 PostScript only.  Also, manually adding to the PostScript file produced by `a2ps` an explicit `PageSize` entry for `setpagedevice` with the page dimensions in points does produce the correct output in Preview and from `pstopdf`.  My question is how to change the default page size assumed by `pstopdf` for example to A4.

Comment: `a2ps` does have a `--setpagedevice` option. Perhaps that's what you need? Failing that, it has a flag for including a PostScript prologue file, so you could try issuing the command in there.

Comment: Using `--setpagedevice=PageSize:"[595 842]"` with `a2ps` works to set the default page size to A4.  This can be made the default by adding `Options: --setpagedevice=PageSize:"[595 842]"` to the `a2ps-site.cfg` file.

Answer (score 1):

If I remove all page size information from a PostScript file, then Preview renders it on a Letter page, even though my default Paper size in CUPS is A4.

There are no user-accessible options or preferences that I can discern. It's certainly undocumented, if it exists.

You may be better off trying to explicitly define the page size in `a2ps`.

Alternative PDF creators, like GhostScript, offer greater control over the output.